# How can I play a sound in a Fragment on button clicked?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments

I have a fragment with two buttons and I want to add sound when the buttons are clicked.

Where do I have to implement the MediaPlayer to play the sound in a fragment?

How can I implement a MediaPlayer to play a sound from raw folder when button is clicked?

This is my code

I have a sound in the raw folder and I need to play it on button clicked in the fragment

```
    package com.example.aprendelastablasdemultiplicar;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
    import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;



    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;

   /**
     * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
     * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
     * {@link explicaciontablas1.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
     * to handle interaction events.
     * Use the {@link explicaciontablas1#newInstance} factory method to
     * create an instance of this fragment.
     */
    public class explicaciontablas1 extends Fragment {
        private Button siguiente;
        private Button atras;

        // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
        // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
        private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

        // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
        private String mParam1;
        private String mParam2;

        private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

        public explicaciontablas1() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment explicaciontablas1.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        public static explicaciontablas1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
            explicaciontablas1 fragment = new explicaciontablas1();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
            args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
}


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            if (getArguments() != null) {
                mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
                mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);


    }


}






        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
           View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explicaciontablas1, container, false);


        Button siguiente = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.siguiente);
        Button atras = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.atras);


            siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment explicacion2 = new explicaciontablas2();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.placeholderfragments, explicacion2);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();

    }
});

        atras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment explicacion2 = new explicaciontablas2();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.placeholderfragments, explicacion2);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
    }
});

        return rootView;


}


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
        public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}


/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

    siguiente and atras are the buttons

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For media player initialization follow this

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public void buttonClickSound(){
    buttonClickSoundStop();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.button_click_sound);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

Check Media player is already start, if start, stop and release it for every click. like this

```
private void buttonClickSoundStop(){
    if (mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```

And then call `buttonClickSound()` from button `onClickListener`. Hope you find your desire answer.